# seleniumIDE - how to store a hyperlinks address and then visit that URL? Was working before

Tags: selenium, hyperlink, ide, href, selenium-ide

I had this working fine a couple of months ago but now when I run the test it fails and I don't know why or how to fix.

Background:
I have a screen with several links so that the 'admin' user who is currently logged in can login as one of the 'practitioners' via the login hyperlink presented.

Details:
So for my test I click on the 'Login link' hyperlink(s), enter & confirm a new password as required, and then I get to the practitioners screen 'as them'.  The 'wrinkle' was that the pop-up for the user to enter their (new) password happened on a new window that the selenium IDE used was a new window.  So basically just clicking on the hyperlink didn't work.  To get around this I was able to `store` the hyperlink's href -`a@href`- in a selenium variable `first_login_link_to` and then use `open` instead of `clickAndWait` to visit the page, i.e. `open ${first_login_link_to}`

This was working fine a few months ago.... but it is not working now.

I get page doesn't exist and when I look at the url - urgh!  It somehow includes the locator stuff and I am getting

`http://dmplanning-stage.herokuapp.com//tr[td[contains(.,'6 Day')]][1]/td[8]/a@href`

instead of

`http://dmplanning-stage.herokuapp.com/p/zaH7m3aL7fxuPLvrc21L`

in the browsers url address bar.

How can I get selenium to `open` the url stored in the variable and not use that 'locator' address?

selenium:

```
open          /admin
clickAndWait  link=practitioners
store         //tr[td[contains(.,'6 Day')]][1]/td[8]/a@href
open          ${first_login_link_to}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it - whew!  Somehow my `storeAttribute` got changed to plain `store`.
Once I changed it back everything worked again!

Comment: Hi Michael; glad you fixed the problem. If you've found a solution and you're not waiting for answers any more, it's best to accept your own answer to take the question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

```
1- 
Command = Store
Target = stuff you want to paste
Value = Var

2- 
Command = sendkeys
Target = id for area where u wana paste
Value = ${Var}

3- 
Command = Fireevent
Target = id for area where u wanna paste
Value = paste
```